# How do I rescale parts of a text defined with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms, text-object

I'm trying to remake the **LUCASFILM** logo with geometry nodes. I can set the position of the text, but I want to set its height. Except it's not just the height of each character; instead, the height of the whole text should change continuously from one side to the other. What am I missing here ?

What I tried: only the vertical position is changed (original image in background):
[image: Only the vertical position is changed]

Need to continuously change the scale:
[image: Need to change the scale]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realize instances to operate on vertex by vertex basis, then just offset by y=sin(x):

[image]

To scale the letters you could use another map range like so:

[image]

The reference image actually scales on letter-by-letter basis:

[image]

You want to reverse that and offset to get the Lucas logo:

[image]

Comment: Raaaaaaawwrrr! :)

Comment: Wonderfulllll! :)

Comment: Thanks ! I needed the MapRange node, which I did not know about. [link](https://imgur.com/L3IGqtA)

Comment: @user513819 nice :). So I see this is actually per vertex displace.

Comment: thank you great explanation and basis for further exploration